# Study materials on finite volume method for conservation laws using Python

Tags: partial-differential-equations, computational-mathematics, python, hyperbolic-equations

I am looking for books/lecture notes/open sources to learn coding finite volume/difference methods in Python for hyperbolic conservation laws(kinda beginner's guide to coding)...

Any help is appreciated..

Thanks!!

Comment: https://github.com/clawpack/riemann_book might be a good place to start, especially if you want coded examples.